# Why am I not able to see my Frame in tkinter Notebook.?

Tags: python, tkinter, tabs

Here is my code. I try to make 2 tabs in my app. the notebook has another frame as its parent.I used pack() in Notebook and place() in Frame

```
notebook = ttk.Notebook(sales_frame)
notebook.pack()
tab1 = Frame(notebook)
notebook.add(tab1,text='tab')
tab2 = Frame(notebook)
notebook.add(tab2,text='tab2')

frame1 = Frame(tab1,bg='red')
frame1.place(x=400, y=200,height=300,width=100)
```

Comment: Please create a complete [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told the notebook to expand to fill its container, so it's going to remain just big enough to hold its contents. You haven't given the contents a size, so the frames in the tabs default to 1x1 pixel wide/tall.

When you add `frame1` to `tab1`, you put it at 400,200. However, `tab1` is only `x` so it won't be visible. Because you use `place`, the size of `frame1` doesn't affect the size of its container, so `tab1` remains at a size of 1x1.

It's almost always better to use `pack` or `grid`, except in very unique situations.

It's impossible to know exactly what advice to give you since it will depend on what else is in the window. However, replacing `place` with either `pack` or `grid` will be a good start. You also probably want `fill="both", expand=True` when packing the notebook in its parent.